How can I optimize query performance in GridDB for large time-series datasets to reduce latency?
I’m currently working on a project that involves using GridDB for managing large time-series datasets. Recently, I’ve been experiencing significant latency issues when querying the database, especially as the dataset continues to grow.
What I’ve Researched:

I’ve read through the official GridDB documentation regarding
indexing and partitioning strategies.
I explored various community
discussions on StackOverflow related to query optimization and
latency reduction in GridDB.
I learned about the importance of using
composite indexes for frequently queried columns.

Steps I’ve Tried:

Indexing: I created a composite index on the timestamp and sensor ID
columns, as these are frequently used in my queries.

Partitioning: I partitioned my time-series data by day to reduce the
amount of data scanned during queries.

Query Optimization: I attempted to utilize GridDB’s aggregation
functions to minimize the data returned.


Code:
import griddb_python

# Connect to GridDB
factory = griddb_python.StoreFactory.get_instance()
gridstore = factory.get_store(host='localhost', port=10001, username='admin', password='password', cluster_name='my_cluster')

# Query to retrieve data
query = "SELECT * FROM my_time_series WHERE sensor_id = ? AND timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ?"
stmt = gridstore.query(query)
stmt.set_string(1, 'sensor_1')
stmt.set_timestamp(2, '2024-01-01 00:00:00')
stmt.set_timestamp(3, '2024-01-31 23:59:59')

# Execute and fetch results
result_set = stmt.fetch()
for row in result_set:
    print(row)


Latency Issue:
Despite these optimizations, I’m still experiencing latency issues. Queries can take several seconds to return results, which is unacceptable for my application that requires near real-time data access.
Questions:

Are there additional indexing strategies or best practices that I might have overlooked?

What other techniques can I employ to further enhance query performance in GridDB and reduce latency for large datasets?


Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
